# RadComboBox reopens after selecting item on IE 11

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have a quick question. I have a RadComboBox with some values. Some of these are very long strings. After selecting one of these long values, the combo keeps reopening. I managed to stop it from reopening by opening another combo. After i click save the selected value in the first combobox is not preserved and returns an empty string.

I was told that RadComboBox has some issues with IE11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of the Telerik controls are you using ?

Comment: I fixed the issue.